# Apply the nested shape of one list on another flat list

Tags: python, arrays, list, algorithm, nested

I have two lists:

A: `[[0, 1], [2, [3]], 4]`

B: `[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

I wish list B could have the same shape with list A:
`[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` => `[[5, 6], [7, [8]], 9]`

So list A and list B have the same dimension/shape:

A: `[[0, 1], [2, [3]], 4]`

B: `[[5, 6], [7, [8]], 9]`

Consider about time complexity, I hope there is a way of O(n) if possible.

Comment: Not really a [numpy] topic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the number of items is identical, you could use a recursive function and an iterator:

```
A = [[0, 1], [2, [3]], 4]
B = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

def copy_shape(l, other):
    if isinstance(other, list):
        other = iter(other)
    if isinstance(l, list):
        return [copy_shape(x, other) for x in l]
    else:
        return next(other)
    
out = copy_shape(A, B)
```

output: `[[5, 6], [7, [8]], 9]`

*NB. the complexity is O(n). You can also use `if hasattr(other, '__len__')` or `if not hasattr(other, '__next__')` in place of `if isinstance(other, list)` to generalize to other iterables (except iterator).*

Answer (score 6):

A one-line variant of @Mozway's idea, using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
A = [[0, 1], [2, [3]], 4]
B = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]


def un_flatten(t, d):
    return [un_flatten(e, d) if isinstance(e, list) else next(d) for e in t]


match = un_flatten(A, iter(B))
print(match)
```

**Output**

```
[[5, 6], [7, [8]], 9]
```

Note that it requires to convert the list `B` to an iterator. The complexity is `O(n)`.

Comment: Essentially the exact same logic as mine with a list comprehension. But nice variant ;) +1

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way with strings and eval -

```py
a = [[0, 1], [2, [3]], 4]
b = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

s = ''
i = 0
for char in str(a):
    if char.isdigit(): # or you can use re.match(r'\w+', char) 
        s += str(b[i])
        i += 1
    else:
        s += char

out_b = eval(s)
```

**Output**

```
[[5, 6], [7, [8]], 9]
```

Comment: Interesting! This one is acturally open my mind. I will try your solution and compare the time consumption with recursive solutions.